# How to pass NGRX Actions to functions as it's parameters in typescript?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular7, ngrx

I have a bit large if else condition in my Angular 7 Application, where I use State manager and rxjs, and would like to make code a bit more readable. In different conditions I need to dispatch different actions. I decided to reduce if else code block with moving some parts to reusable function, and need to pass NGRX actions to those functions as parameters. But typescript throws an error: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type.

The question is - what type I should define for actions? As setSomeDataAction: Action - doesn't work

Code now:

```
if (mobile) {         
  if (newVisitor) {
      this.store.dispatch(SetMobileForNewVisitor(payload));
  } else {
      this.store.dispatch(SetMobileForExistingVisitor(payload));
  }
} else {
  if (newVisitor) {
     this.store.dispatch(SetNotMobileForNewVisitor(payload));
  } else {
     this.store.dispatch(SetNotMobileForExistingVisitor(payload));
  }
}
```

Code which throws typescript Error

```
mobile ?
this.dispatchRemoveOne(SetMobileForNewVisitor, SetMobileForExistingVisitor, payload) :
this.dispatchRemoveOne(SetNotMobileForNewVisitor,SetNotMobileForExistingVisitor, payload);

private dispatchRemoveOne(newVisitorAction, existingVisitorAction, payload) {
    newVisitor
      ? this.store.dispatch(newVisitorAction(payload))
      : this.store.dispatch(existingVisitorAction(payload));
  }
```

I was trying something like:

```
private dispatchRemoveOne(newVisitorAction: Action, existingVisitorAction: Action, payload: Payload[]) {
    newVisitor
      ? this.store.dispatch(newVisitorAction(payload))
      : this.store.dispatch(existingVisitorAction(payload));
  }
```

Comment: Why not do the logic in reducer, it seems more natural there

Comment: @FanCheung reducer should be simple. We must not do logic caculation inside reducer

Comment: There maybe no fix answer on this really. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227419/react-redux-should-reducers-contain-any-logic, it just seems having 4 conditional checking on devices, makes the code cleaner if in reducer.

Comment: why not do it in a effect?