# ngrx adpter updateOne

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have issue with ngrx adapter,
How can I update reducer based on parametr from action?

I tried to make a find method from rxjs but I had "overlap" error.

Both as main interface and status interface share one key parametr, but it is not id.

Here is piece of a code:

Action:

```
export const verifyDocument = createAction('[Document/API] Verify Document', props<{ status: Status }>());
```

Reducer:

```
const _documentReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
      on(DocumentActions.upsertDocuments, (state, { documents }) => {
        return adapter.upsertMany(documents, state);
      }),
      on(DocumentActions.verifyDocument, (state, { status }) => {

        const records = {...state.entities}


        console.log("reducer: ", records, status, "end.");
        return state;
        //return adapter.updateOne(???, state);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try implementing it in the following approach:

First create a `selector` so you can get the object by the desired property:

```js
export const getPersonByName = createSelector(getPeopleEntities, (people: Person[], name: string) => people.find(x = x.name == name));
```

Utilizing an `Effect` which would listen to `UpdateByNameAction` and in its turn will dispatch a `UpdatePesonByIdAction` will allow your expected behavior:

```js
public findByName$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$
 .pipe(
    ofType(SchemaActionTypes.FindByName),
    switchMap(name => this.store.pipe(select(getPersonByName, name))),
    map((person) => authAction.updatePesonByIdAction(person, person.id))
  )
);
```

Comment: Please refer to the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47228099/9369606